# Send email message eml c#

Tags: c#, email, sendmail, cdo.message, eml

Currently, I have an email  application and I want to add send messages with .eml but not as attached file without from, to content. I don't know where to start. My first idea was extract message from .eml file and return CDO message.

Comment: I think you should parse content of you eml file, and use results for fields of your email. Do you know structure of eml file?

Comment: There isn't official RFC for it. But usually it stored in rfc0822. You can find  it here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt . What is source of your eml files?

Comment: I need to add to the message from eml file to MailMessage class.

Comment: DO you looking for solution or for ready library?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possibly looking at the OpenPop.NET library (http://hpop.sourceforge.net/). MIME parsing is included and, as far as I can remember, functioned OK for me once. I have the impression that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I need to add to the message from eml file to  MailMessage class.